# Project Euler #12 in C++ - highly divisible triangular number

Tags: c++, c++11, project-euler, primes

[Project Euler Problem 12](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12) asks (paraphrased):

> The *n*<sup>th</sup> triangular number *T*<sub>*n*</sub> = 1 + 2 + … + *n*.  *T*<sub>7</sub> = 28 has 6 divisors (1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28).  What is the first *T*<sub>*n*</sub> to have over 500 divisors?

After asking for some help on Stack Overflow, I've managed to write this code to solve it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
//#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int divisors (unsigned int num, std::map<int, int>& map) 
{
    int orig_num = num;
    for(unsigned int i = 2; i <= num; ++i)
    {
        while (num % i == 0) 
        {
            num /= i;
            ++map[i];
            //std::cout << map[i] << "\t";
        }
    }
    std::cout << orig_num << " = "; 
    for(auto& iter:map)
        std::cout << iter.first <<  "^" << iter.second << " * ";
    return 0;
}

int overall_factors(unsigned int n)
{
    std::map <int, int> primefactors1, primefactors2; 
    int no_of_divisors = 1;
    divisors(n,primefactors1);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    divisors(n+1,primefactors2);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::map<int, int> primefactors_triangle = std::accumulate( primefactors1.begin(), primefactors1.end(), std::map<int, int>(),
        []( std::map<int, int> &m, const std::pair<const int, int> &p )
    {
        return ( m[p.first] +=p.second, m );
    } );

    primefactors_triangle = std::accumulate( primefactors2.begin(), primefactors2.end(), primefactors_triangle,
        []( std::map<int, int> &m, const std::pair<const int, int> &p )
    {
        return ( m[p.first] +=p.second, m );
    } );

    for ( const auto &p : primefactors_triangle )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
        if (p.first == 2)
            no_of_divisors *= p.second;
        else
        no_of_divisors *= p.second+1;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return no_of_divisors;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    while (overall_factors(i) < 500)
    {
        std::cout << overall_factors(i) << std::endl;
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There're some pieces left that output debugging info to see that everything is working as intended. But overall, it doesn't work as fast as I want it to - or as fast as I expect a proper solution to a Project Euler problem to work.

How can this code be improved?  Clearly the program, as it is, now calculates `primefactors` for a given number twice.  What else is wrong and could be improved?

UPD: After I changed the `while` loop condition, the problem was solved rather quickly. Still, I believe my code is improvable.

Comment: [Optimization hints](http://stackoverflow.com/a/571526/4279) (Implementation in Python takes around 50ms)

Answer (score 4):

- This:

  ```
  int i = 2;
  while (overall_factors(i) < 500)
  {
      std::cout << overall_factors(i) << std::endl;
      ++i;
  }
  ```

  can just be a `for`-loop:

  ```
  for (int i = 2; overall_factors(i) < 500; ++i)
  {
      std::cout << overall_factors(i) << std::endl;
  }
  ```

  I'd also recommend using a constant for `500` as it is otherwise a magic number.  This will make it clear as to what this value represents.

  If the number isn't significant to the general algorithm, then a comment can be added instead.
- There is no need for `divisors` to just return a 0.  It appears it's just modifying the map and displaying it.  Also, these are two different things, and a function should just have one role.  In this case, it should just modify the map.  You should then have a separate `void` function for displaying the map in the desired format.

  Although passing the map by reference is okay here, passing it by value (in C++11) will also allow the compiler to decide to perform a move, if desired over a copy.

Comment: Thanks. Could I just add a really clear comment about the intent behind `500` instead of using a constant for it?

Comment: You may, especially if the number is not that significant to the algorithm.

Comment: originally the code had a commented link to the original project euler page about the problem (it's still in the code on my PC), therefore I expected anyone who'd read the code to read the problem statement & have a clear idea about the meaning of 500.

Comment: I primarily meant that in general, as it's preferable to use as few magic numbers as possible.  Not *every* such number needs a constant, just ones with a meaning behind them.

Comment: Got it, will try to follow yor advice.

Comment: @Jamal: If parameter `map` in `divisors` is not needed (besides initializing `newMap`) then pass it by value and modify it instead. This avoids a copy an unused variable.

Comment: @Nobody: That *may* be okay, if `map` is small and passing by value doesn't prove expensive.  There's also move semantics, but I was hesitant about mentioning it since I've read that utilizing RVO is still preferred.

Comment: @Jamal: passing `map` by value is no more expensive than making a copy in the function. Especially, it may be more efficient in C++11 since the compiler gets to decide between a copy and a move at parameter-passing time.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA: That is a good point.  I'm not sure why I've considered this different.  I'll update it.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do immediately to cut your running time by a large factor is to modify your `main` function:

```
int main() {
    int num_factors = 0;
    for (int i = 2; num_factors < 500; ++i) {
        num_factors = overall_factors(i);
        std::cout << num_factors << "\n";
    }
}
```

Two things:

1. I only compute `overall_factors(i)` once instead of twice for each value of `i`.
2. I output `"\n"`, not `std::endl`, to end the line. `std::endl` not only outputs a line break, it flushes `std::cout`. Flushing output buffers is slow.

Likewise, convert your `std::cout << std::endl` elsewhere into `std::cout << "\n"` (or remove in-function input entirely) and you'll see a marked speed improvement. The buffer will automatically flush from time to time; if you want to see more frequent flushing, you can add this to your main loop:

```
if (!(i % 10)) std::cout << std::flush;
```

As to the rest of your code, it is somewhat difficult to review. Your functions and their parameters have uninformative names (e.g. `map` is not a good name for a `map` you're passing; `primefactorization` would be better in that case). Your lambdas confusingly return a statement of the form `return (foo(), bar());`; it is misleading to use the comma operator like that -- this isn't Python, your lambdas are allowed multiple statements!

Why do you use `accumulate` at all? You can just pass the same map to both calls of `divisors` and get the same result as accumulating the two.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the flushing issue. Also, I used `accumulate` to see how to - in other words, as an exercise. So I agree that there's a possibly better solution without it.

Answer (score 2):

At a quick first-glance, one thing you can do that should cut run-time quite a bit is to change that STL map of ints to ints to an array of ints. I'm not sure how big your keys get, but even for some pretty large sizes this should be much quicker, but perhaps less elegant. In general STL maps have a reputation for being somewhat slow, so if you can eliminate your dependency on this data structure (a red-black tree) somehow, things should speed up.